# In MySQL, get number of pregnant women who received 3 ANC checkups

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, subquery

I am working on a project where it is required to find out the total number of pregnant women who have received 3 ANC(Ante-Natal Care) checkups done.

A pregnant women is said to receive 3 ANC checkups if any 3 of the 4 columns(visit1_date,visit2_date,visit3_date and visit4_date) have some value.

For this, I need to calculate the count of number of rows where any 3 of 4 columns given in the table are not null.

So, basically, what is required is to find a count of all rows where any three of

visit1_date, visit2_date,visit3_date,visit4_date are NOT NULL

My table has columns individually for each of the visit dates

I have tried using IFNULL, but I have no idea if this would help.

Comment: See normalisation. This is no way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, a boolean operation is treated as a number in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.  This makes it easy to count the number of non-NULL values:

```
select count(*)
from table t
where ((visit1_date is not null) +
       (visit2_date is not null) +
       (visit3_date is not null) +
       (visit4_date is not null)
      ) >= 3;
```